# linq multiple order DESCENDING

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

```
.OrderBy(y => y.Year).ThenBy(m => m.Month);
```

How to set `descending` order?

**EDIT**:

I tried this:

```
var result = (from dn in db.DealNotes
                         where dn.DealID == dealID                         
                         group dn by new { month = dn.Date.Month, year = dn.Date.Year } into date
                         orderby date.Key.year descending
                         orderby date.Key.month descending
                         select new DealNoteDateListView { 
                             DisplayDate = date.Key.month + "-" + date.Key.year,
                             Month = date.Key.month,
                             Year = date.Key.year,
                             Count = date.Count()
                         })
                         //.OrderBy(y => y.Year).ThenBy(m => m.Month)
                         ;
```

And it seems working. Is it wrong to use `orderby` twice like I used it here?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can get the descending ordering by using a different pair of methods:

```
items.OrderByDescending(y => y.Year).ThenByDescending(m => m.Month);
```

Using LINQ query, you can write:

```
from date in db.Dates
orderby date.Key.year descending, date.Key.month descending 
select new { ... }
```

The trick is that you need only one `orderby` clause - if you add multiple of these, the list will be re-sorted each time. To sort elements that have the first key equal using another key, you need to separate them using `,` (`orderby` is translated to `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` while `,` is translated to `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending`).